# A strange error in rails remote_ip middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is the error I found on rails production enviroment:

```
IP spoofing attack?!HTTP_CLIENT_IP="10.127.166.241"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="10.127.166.241, 61.164.36.180"
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:55:in `calculate_ip'
```

So I digg into the rails [remote_ip.rb](https://codeclimate.com/github/rails/rails/ActionDispatch%3a%3aRemoteIp%3a%3aIpSpoofAttackError) sourcecode, go over `calculate_ip`, tested it locally, and found it should not happen, here is the test code:

```
forwarded_ips = "10.127.166.241, 61.164.36.180".strip.split(/[,\s]+/).reverse
client_ips ="10.127.166.241".strip.split(/[,\s]+/).reverse
!forwarded_ips.include?(client_ips.last) # return false?
```

According to my understanding after read the source code, caculate_ip sould return `61.164.36.180` instand of an error, anyone knows why? thanks~